# Android - Animate Intent but leave out View

Tags: android, android-intent, android-animation, android-view

I have a couple of `Activities` which all contain one `CustomView`, a titlebar. I need to make an `overridePendingTransition()` to animate the `Intent`.

Is there a way to not animate the titlebar when transforming one `View` to the other? Like make it just stick to the top...

Hope you understand my problem!

**Edit:**

Here's some pseudocode for how one of these `Acitvities` look like:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <CustomView />
  <Linearlayout>
    ... (other views)
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit II:**

Just to make my problem clear: I have several `Activities` which all have the same custom titlebar. I need to animate the Intent (going from one `Activity` to the other). I don't have a problem with any logic - I just need the titlebar to stay where it is before the animation. The position is in every `Activity` the same (on the top).

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment in response to Gagan I think you're confusing Views and Activities.You can have an Activity that inflates and uses Views and Layouts that are all kept in their own files and classes.  Unless I'm missing something your individual logic for the Views can all be broken out and as long as they have access to the parent context they can communicate to the parent (if they need to).

If your intention is to have all these "Activities" sharing screen space (in some configuration) then you're definitely confusing the concepts and not really grasping how Views work... keep in mind that a View can be a Layout that can contain any number of children (and whatever business logic you need to have them all do whatever it is you need them to do).

Comment: I had an error in my post. I meant activities which contain views and a custom titlebar. I fixed that.

Comment: Fragments are definitely an option, but if you're in a version of Android the predates Fragments you can still break your code out into individual custom Views with their own logic, that can all live under one Activity... you just have to be clever about it.

Comment: The API version is no problem. But it seems that I have to restructure all my `Activities` when I use them as `Fragments`. Is there really no easy way to exclude one `View` from beeing animated?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears that titlebar has common UI elements for your `Views`.
In this case you can think about taking titlebar out of the `Views` and keep only your `CustomView`  inside a `View`.
Now place single instance of your titlebar on top of the `Views` containing your `CustomView`.
Something like below:

[image]

This way when you transform from one view to another your titlebar would remain static and will not animate.

**[EDIT - Alternative for multiple `activities`]**

If choice of transition is not fixed then you can use `alpha animation` to transform from one activity to another. I have used this in one of my apps and works as you described in your query.

Create your `alpha animation` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />
```

Comment: good thinking... any idea how i can put the titlebar on top of the views? my titlebar is in my case the `CustomView`. the `activities` contains regular `view` elements

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. Simplest to achieve this would be by using a `LinearLayout`.
Define two layouts inside a `LinearLayout` - one for `TitleBar` and another for holding your `CustomViews`. Set the orientation of your parent `LinearLayout` to `Vertical`. This should suffice.
Moreover, it would help greatly if you can paste your code too.

Comment: but if i just take a `LinearLayout` then i still would be in the same `Activity`. some of my `Actvities` contain loads of logic so i'd prefer to keep them separated...

Comment: Now your query is more clear. I've edited my answer. Please check. Hope it does what you want.

Comment: But alpha just manages the opacity right? It would still fade out the bar and then fade it in again. I don't want any animation for the titlebar and the full animation for the rest.

Comment: True, alpha is for managing opacity. Having said that, please note that you will be applying `alpha-animation` to your to-be-launched `activity` and your current activity's titlebar's opacity is 100% hence no animation would be visible for titlebar as each activity has same titlebar.

Comment: :) We'll have to think about something else then.